# How to declare foreign keys in Apache Derby?

Tags: java, foreign-keys, derby

I am trying to make a R.D.B. at the moment, but I can't seem to get the foreign keys working. When running the program, the two tables without foreign keys (Words and PDFs) are created and then it has a run-time error at the Index table:

> Table 'INDEX' contains a constraint definition with column 'WORDID' which is not in the table. Derby shut down normally

Here is my code:

```
new String createSQL3 = "create table Index (" 
        + " IndexID integer not null generated always as"
        + " identity (start with 1, increment by 1),"
        + " IndexPage integer not null, IndexOccurences integer not null,"
        + " constraint IndexID_PK primary key (IndexID),"
        + " constraint WordID_FK FOREIGN KEY (WordID) REFERENCES Words(WordID),"
        + " constraint PDFID_FK FOREIGN KEY (PDFID) REFERENCES PDFs(PDFID))";
            
        statement.execute(createSQL3);
        System.out.println("Table Index created successfully");
         
        connection.commit();
        
    } catch (SQLException EX) {
        System.out.println(EX.getMessage());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax:

```
constraint WordID_FK FOREIGN KEY (WordID) REFERENCES Words(WordID)
```

says that you want the column `WordID` in the table `Index` to be a reference to the column `WordID` in the table `Words`.

But you did not define a column named `WordID` in the table `Index`, as the message says. Your `Index` table has only three columns: `IndexID`, `IndexPage`, and `IndexOccurrences`.

You probably want to have something like

```
WordID integer,
```

in your definition of table `Index`.